# How to extract Email Domain from Email Address within Google Big Query

Tags: sql, email, google-bigquery

I've got a load of customer data and I'm trying to find a way within Big Query to extract the email domain (so yahoo.com out of test@yahoo.com for example) however any attempts I've made using normal SQL doesn't seem to work as they don't support CHARINDEX while any substrings can only be created based on a numeric value.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could do this?

Cheers,

Matt

Answer (score 15):

You could use the `REGEXP_EXTRACT` function --

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT('matt@yahoo.com', r'@(.+)');
```

would give 'yahoo.com'.

Answer (score 3):

This is by far the easiest, I think:

```
SPLIT(email_address, '@')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] as domain
```

Comment: Better use `SAFE_OFFSET`

Answer (score 1):

This is sql Query might help somone.

```
declare @email varchar(50) ='Abcxyz@subdomain.domain.com';
SELECT SUBSTRING(@email, CHARINDEX('@', @email) + 1, LEN(@email) - CHARINDEX('@', @email) + 1) AS domain_name
```

**Output**
subdomain.domain.com

```
DECLARE @var varchar(50) ='test@subdoamin.domain.com';
SELECT 
SUBSTRING(@var,0,charindex('@',@var)) as UserName,
Substring(@var,charindex('@',@var)+1,charindex('.',@var,charindex('@',@var,0))-(charindex('@',@var)+1)) as SubDomain,
substring(@var,charindex('.',@var,charindex('@',@var))+1,len(@var)) as DomainName
```

**Output**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best option if you don't want ".com"

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT("matt@yahoo.com", "@(\\w+)") AS domain;
```

Will give you only "yahoo"